# Making two squares with two different functions, (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, components

I am attempting to make two squares side by side, one that chooses a random location, and another with a fixed location. I'm doing this by making two component functions, each with different properties. However, whenever I  attempt to add the component2 function, an error appears that says unexpected end to input towards the very end of my code. This prevents me from running the code. What can I do to fix this?

```html
<html>
 <head>
 
  
 </head>
<body>

<p> Click Start Game to play </p>
<div id="start">Start Game</div>
<div id="hi">Hi</div>




<script>




function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image"){
 this.image = new Image();
 this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.color=color;
    this.update = function() {
       random = Math.floor((Math.random()*200) + 1);
       random2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*200) + 1);
       function getRandomColor() {
           var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
           var color = '#';
           for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
              color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
           return color;
       }
       randcolor=getRandomColor();
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "image"){
     ctx.drawImage(this.image, random, random2, random,random2);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = randcolor;
            ctx.fillRect(random, random2, 50, 50);
        }
        this.x=random;
        this.y=random2;
        this.width=50;
        this.height=50;
        this.color=randcolor;
    }

}


function component2(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image"){
 this.image = new Image();
 this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "image"){
     ctx.drawImage(this.image,this.x, this.y, this.width,this.height);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
        this.y = this.y + this.speedY;
 //removed hitting rock bottom because the background and other pieces will be off screen.
 
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
     board =1;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
function startGame() {
 random = Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1);


 random2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1);


 square = new component(50, 50, "green", random, random2);
 myGamePiece = new component(30, 40, "greenhorn.gif", 220, 120,"image");
myGameArea.start();
return square  
}



var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
 
        this.canvas.width = 450;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 1000);
        },
    clear : function() {
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}



function updateGameArea() {
    
    myGameArea.clear();
    square.update();

}




document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', startGame);
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You don't ever close the `component2` function. add `}` wherever you want to close it (I'm going to assume before `startGame`

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional closing curly bracket after

```
        return crash;
    } 
} // this is missing
```

```js
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.color = color;
    this.update = function () {
        random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);
        random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);
        function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
        }
        randcolor = getRandomColor();
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "image") {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, random, random2, random, random2);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = randcolor;
            ctx.fillRect(random, random2, 50, 50);
        }
        this.x = random;
        this.y = random2;
        this.width = 50;
        this.height = 50;
        this.color = randcolor;
    }

}

function component2(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function () {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "image") {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function () {
        this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
        this.y = this.y + this.speedY;
        //removed hitting rock bottom because the background and other pieces will be off screen.

    }
    this.hitBottom = function () {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
            board = 1;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function (otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}
function startGame() {
    random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    square = new component(50, 50, "green", random, random2);
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 40, "greenhorn.gif", 220, 120, "image");
    myGameArea.start();
    return square
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start: function () {
        this.canvas.width = 450;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 1000);
    },
    clear: function () {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    square.update();
}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', startGame);
```

```html
<p>Click Start Game to play</p>
<div id="start">Start Game</div>
<div id="hi">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to make the second component work?

Comment: what should `component2` do? btw, you need to declare some variables and you need some public variables, like `square`, because the callback for an event does not return something.